# Spatial Query for a Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, sql, spatial-query, virtual-layer

I would like to use SQL to create a virtual layer in QGIS by clipping information from a large data set using a bounding box around my study area.

[image: Diagram of GUI Feedback]

I have two questions.  Is this an efficient way to work with large data sets (i.e., more efficient than just loading a large shapefile)?

How do I write the query? for it?  I don't really know what I am doing, so far my query looks like this:

```
Select F* Where ST_Intersects(F.geometry,C.geometry)
```

At the moment, I keep crashing my computer with my queries.  I will post back if I figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sample syntax for you.

```
SELECT *
FROM F, C
WHERE st_within(F.geometry, C.geometry) = 1
```

On a side note:

- `SELECT *` will output everything (including geometry column) fits your conditions.
- `FROM F,C` will define the datasource
- `WHERE` is the condition, and `st_intersects()` requires `1 (TRUE)` or `0 (FALSE)`. I chose `st_within()` for your case.

I hope testing this and comparing the speed with other methods answers your first question, too.