# Queries for subset sub-setted data spatially in Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis-3, sql, query, virtual-layer

I need to fiddle together some small but smart queries in a Virtual Layer.

I have a growing GPKG of field observations, and for easier analysis of the progress, I would like to create some queries in a Virtual Layer instead of having to redo tedious filtering and sorting every second day, producing unnecessary layers.

In the field work, I take observations of various species around a target area, but in the end I only need the observations of one species in a special zone.

So, the easy part is to subset the observations to the species from a given date on:

**obs:**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM observations AS o
WHERE o.date > '2021-04-01'
AND o.species = 'ze'
```

Now I would also like to filter out the observations outside of *'area 1'* of the layer *"areas"*. For this I can subset the area layer by:

**area:**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM areas AS a
WHERE a.name = 'area 1'
```

When I try to make a third query, spatially sub-setting the sub-setted observations within the sub-setted area,

```sql
SELECT *
FROM obs AS o, area AS a
WHERE st_within(o.geometry, a.geometry) = 1
```

`st_within()`... taken from [Spatial Query for a Virtual Layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/268615/8202)

Comment: With *"how to merge all three queries into a single query?"*, do you simply mean writing all queries together in one or something else?

Comment: Hi Taras, yep, writing all queries in one. I lost the term nesting. Funnily, in german language, we are able to nest multiple sentences into each other, so the concept should be clear to me, but for some reason, I do not get it with sql ;)

Comment: Extremely good comparison with "nesting" German language :)

Comment: Argh, I'm in despair. In the hunt for the bug, I saved the relevant data to a new directory, created a new project, even started with a new profile ... and now the result of the query is 0! Zero, nothing. Querying for the attribute subset works, but as the spatial part comes into play, everything is gone. Bug or feature?

Comment: Is there data inside of your layers in that directory?

Comment: Yes, everything is there. I just exported the observations and areas and arranged everything like it was before

Comment: The query still "works" in the old project, but with those lots of missing features. I don't get it.

Comment: Ok, think I got a trace: I copied all features of my observations, and pasted them in a new scratch layer. It says that it also has 266 features, but when I select them on the map window, only 119 are selected. So, it seams my gpkg is somehow corrupted. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To merge/bring all the queries under one roof, possible to achieve by means of the [WITH clause](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-with-clause/):

```sql
WITH Q1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM observations AS o
    WHERE o.date > '2021-04-01'
      AND o.species = 'ze'),

Q2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM areas AS a
    WHERE a.name = 'area 1'),

Q3 AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM obs AS o, area AS a
    WHERE st_within(o.geometry, a.geometry) = 1)

SELECT ...
FROM Q1, Q2, Q3
WHERE ...
```

However, in your case I would simply work with one query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM observations AS o, areas AS a
WHERE o.date > '2021-04-01' AND o.species = 'ze'
AND a.name = 'area 1'
AND st_within(Q1.geometry, Q2.geometry) = 1
```

BTW you can also nest query into another, i.e.:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM observations AS o
      WHERE o.date > '2021-04-01'
       AND o.species = 'ze') AS Q1,
      (SELECT *
       FROM areas AS a
       WHERE a.name = 'area 1') AS Q2
WHERE st_within(Q1.geometry, Q2.geometry) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The nested query was the one I was looking for. But now that I try your solution, there is still this huge lack of points generated by the query. And its still exactly the 80 from 147 as I found out earlier. Will attach an image to the question.

Comment: I had to uncheck the answer. With the latter query, I get inconsistent to no results.For the last hours, I am trying to replicate the stuff in the DB Manager, and there this query just throws every matching point in every area, so I just get 3 times more results (I have three areas) than it should have.

Comment: Can you share your data (or a part of it)?

Comment: I gladly do: https://filebin.net/e7m9q71pwignpk9o

My layers and fields have other names in reality.

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM Aufnahmen AS a
      WHERE a.datum > '2021-01-01'
       AND a.art = 'ze') AS Q1,
      (SELECT *
       FROM Zonen AS z
       WHERE z.name = 'A1') AS Q2
WHERE st_within(Q1.geometry, Q2.geometry) = 1

Comment: Ok, I made it. Had to add the coordinate columns, export to csv and then reimport the points. Obviously there was something wrong with the data type. The previous PointZ layer did not work, now it is a Point and works fine. Thanx again and sorry for the trouble

Comment: Let me know if something still going wrong. Text me directly here: https://discord.com/invite/h2rks6N